# My class says it does't have a function when it does. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

In my class world:

```
class world:
    def __init__(self):
        if self != 'start_room':
            pass
        else: 
            self.isenemy = random.choice([True, False])
            if isenmey == False:
                self.istrap = random.choice([True, False])

        def enter_room(self):
            if self.isenemy:
                fight()
            elif self.istrap:
                trap()
            else:
                print('The room is empty')
```

when I run this code:

```
rooms[current_room].enter_room()
```

I get an error that says:

> 'world' object has no attribute 'enter_room'

I'm new to Stackoverflow, Python, PEP8, and even newer to classes in python, so be easy on me.

Edit:
I fixed the old problem now I have the error:

> 'world' object has no attribute 'isenemy'

Comment: Your indent is wrong.

Comment: were is the indent that is wrong

Comment: Also, consider naming your classes in UpperCamelCase to distinguish them from normal functions, naming your class like this : `class World:` ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have a typo on the 7th row. Align your def enter_room with def **init**

```
class world:
    def __init__(self):
        if self != 'start_room':
            pass
        else: 
            self.isenemy = random.choice([True, False])
            if isenmey == False:
                self.istrap = random.choice([True, False])

    def enter_room(self):
        if self.isenemy:
            fight()
        elif self.istrap:
            trap()
        else:
            print('The room is empty')
```

Comment: I fixed that in my code.

Comment: @hackerHD That's the sole issue that I see, and you didn't edit your question to indicate there's any other issues.

Answer (score 1):

You put unexpected indentations. Your function `enter_room()` is defined inside `__init()__`. There you go :

```
class world:
    def __init__(self):
        if self != 'start_room':
            pass
        else: 
            self.isenemy = random.choice([True, False])
            if isenmey == False:
                self.istrap = random.choice([True, False])

    def enter_room(self):
        if self.isenemy:
            fight()
        elif self.istrap:
            trap()
        else:
            print('The room is empty')
```